# How to ignore '$' is not defined JsLint Error. (Visual Studio 2010 JsLint Extentsion)

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, jslint

I am trying to get my error count down. Lots of the things that JsLint complains about I don't find are really errors but more personal preference in my option(like braces on their own line).

It comes up with

> JS Lint: '$' is not defined.

In all my files that use the short hand document rdy in jquery. I really don't think I should be defining it. Is there away to skip this check?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On the JSLint website, there's a textbox towards the bottom right called "predefined." Add `$` and the errors should go away.

Update:

With the VS2010 plugin, there's a similarly-named "Predefined Vars" textbox in the options dialog (look to the right of "Strict white space indendation":

[image]

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker - Sorry I should mention I am using the Vs2010 jslint extension.

Comment: @chobo2, you should edit that information into your question.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker  - Cool. Do I need to add "window" to this list as I also get JS Lint: 'window' is not defined.

Comment: @chobo2: Yes, I would also check "Assume a browser."

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker  - Did that and it still shows up as a error.

Comment: @chobo2: Make sure the list is comma-separated. Also, did allowing `$` ever work, or is that not working either?

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
/*global $ */
```

at the top as per [How to fix "foo is not defined" error reported by JSlint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957977/how-to-fix-foo-is-not-defined-error-reported-by-jslint)

You can fill it up with your own declarations like

```
/*global language, console, whatever, cool, lib, $ */
```

I wish it would read

```
/// <reference path="Jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js" />
```

though, as Visualstudio itself does.