# How to fix "foo is not defined" error reported by JSlint?

Tags: javascript, jslint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSLint: was used before it was defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621162/jslint-was-used-before-it-was-defined)

I run `JSlint` and saw errors like that:

```
'foo' is not defined.
var x = foo();
```

`foo` is a function defined in another `JavaScript` file `foo.js`. As I understand there is no "import / require" directives in `JavaScript` to reference the `foo` function defined in another source file.

How can I fix this error repoted by `JSlint`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSLint: was used before it was defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621162/jslint-was-used-before-it-was-defined) and [“`[Variable]` was used before it was defined” error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134049/variable-was-used-before-it-was-defined-error).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use the global directive to tell JSLint about `foo`'s assumed existence.

```
/*global foo */
```

http://www.jslint.com/help.html#global

Comment: I alway's thought it was without space: `/*global`

Comment: You're right; I wasn't sure it actually made a difference. Then I tested, and `/*global` works but `/* global` doesn't.

Comment: you just beat me to it by a second haha, figured to add this as a comment since the question is indeed a duplicate

Comment: This is good but I don't like to litter my production code with test or code quality snippets. I think it would be better to declare these in a separate file confined to the test environment.

Comment: @BSeven since it's a comment, your JS minification tooling should remove it automatically for production, right? `:)`

Comment: My concern is not about download speed. It's pollution of the source that is read by developers.

Comment: I see. When you said "production code" I thought you meant "code that users receive."

Comment: I manually added `socket.io` into my client html, and js (angular controller) and got "io not defined", while running `gulp build`. This method works well.

Comment: There also is a `.jshintrc` file that has a `globals` section where you can define those. That way you don't have to pollute your source files with things like that.